# html-minifier node.js TypeError: value.replace is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, minify

I am trying to minify html file using the node module html-minifier. In order to this I have created this little node.js file which should be able to do this

```
'use strict'

var fs = require('fs');
var minifier = require('html-minifier').minify;

var htmlFile = fs.readFileSync("users/email/test.html");
var output = minifier(htmlFile, {
    removeAttributeQuotes: true
});

process.stdout.write(output);
```

but when I run the program I get the following error.

```
TypeError: value.replace is not a function
```

Any idea why this is happening. I am using version 4.0.0 of html-minifier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you haven't specified a text encoding, `readFileSync` returned a `Buffer`, not a string. See the [`readFileSync` documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_path_options).

If you know the encoding to use, you can specify it as a second argument:

```
var htmlFile = fs.readFileSync("users/email/test.html", "utf8");
```

Comment: yup that fixed it.